# log4j writing to rolled over file

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

We have set log4j rollover as 500mb upon 500 mb it is creating a file new file log.1 but still it is sometimes writing to log.1 and to log and sometimes only to log and some times to log.1.
I am using apache tomcat.
It is so inconsistent.

```
 <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p: %c - %m%n" />
            </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="maxFileSize" value="500MB" />
            <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
            <param name="Append" value="true"/>
            <param name="File" value="c:/logs/web.log" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n" />
            </layout>
    </appender>
```

Could you please let me know any reason for this?

Regards,
Adam

Comment: Can you give us the log4j property file?

Comment: Could you please tell me is there any settings in log4j which will go and write to archived logs or any bugs identified in old log4j?

Comment: Is this fixed? and how?